# C# WPF navgation menu

Tags: c#, navigation, wpf-controls

I want to create a GUI in c# (Wpf) with visual studio.

So what I have: I started working at it already, but i made every window as an xaml and code behind, every wpf window had a button "continue" to get to the next window (open new one , close actual one)

I want to restructure it: I want like a navigation menu vertically at the left side:

MODULE 1

MODULE 2

MODULE 3

MODULE 4

When i click For example Module one , on the right side of the window should appear the stuff to configure module 1. it can be something with listboxes and stuff, but it is important that every module i select in the navigation will have different controls to different bindings on the right, like i want a single class for every module. The modules should be abke to communicate, like have access to lists of other classes

Is there some control i can use to do this nav. Menu?

I am happy for all the help i can get.

Comment: TabControl with a different datacontext for every TabItem might be what you are looking for. You would then just have to use differents usercontrols in each TabItem

Comment: So I would just have one Xaml file? I'd have 7 tabs and every would have different controls, it would be a long xaml code for the one file, can i split it somehow? If not, will I have access to the controls if i create one class for every tab which stands for a module?

Comment: If you use users controls you shouldn't have that much xaml : <TabControl><TabItem><yourUserContro /></TabItem>TabItem><yourOtherUserControl/></TabItem><!--etc--></TabControl>

Comment: Can I add a method that gets called when i change a tab , specified for every single tab? I know there is te method that can be called when tab selection changed, but i need like a different method that is called referring to which tab you selected, i could add a button "save" to every tab but i'd prefer a method that does it automatically when i leave the tab

Comment: Yup, just add SelectionChanged="youreventName" in your tabcontrol declaration.
Then in your event the sender object is your tab control and you can see wich tabitem is selected, then it's up to you to add some behaviour depending on you selected tabitem name or else